# Python 2.7. Save text file's name as date with linux command

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, shell, file

I am using subprocess() to do linux shell commands in python and what i wanna do is read a file, get the needed info and save it in a text file named by current date. Reading and all works fine, but I don't know how to save file by naming it with current date. I tried making a variable with subprocess, but that was not successful.

```
def gauti():
        imti=tekstas.get("1.0", "end-1c")
        subprocess.call("data=$(date +"%d_%m_%Y")", shell=True)
        subprocess.call("grep -i '{imti}' /var/log/syslog > $data.txt".format(imti=imti), shell=True)
```

Comment: "I tried making a variable with subprocess, but that was not successful". Please show your code.

Comment: added. Forgot about it

Answer (score 2):

This code will never work:

```
subprocess.call("data=$(date +"%d_%m_%Y")", shell=True)
subprocess.call("grep -i '{imti}' /var/log/syslog > $data.txt".format(imti=imti), shell=True)
```

Because a new shell is created every time, so your $data variable is not passed from the first command to the second.  You can just do this:

```
subprocess.check_call("grep -i '{}' /var/log/syslog > $(date +%d_%m_%Y.txt)".format(imti), shell=True)
```